# Hash differs from sha1sum when using fgets

Tags: c, openssl, fgets

I am trying to write a simple hashing program.  This is the code:

```
#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    unsigned char hash[EVP_MAX_MD_SIZE];
    unsigned hash_size;
    unsigned i;
    char s[100];

    EVP_MD_CTX *ctx = EVP_MD_CTX_create();
    EVP_MD_CTX_init(ctx);
    EVP_DigestInit_ex(ctx, EVP_sha1(), NULL);

    while (fgets(s, sizeof(s), stdin))
    {
        EVP_DigestUpdate(ctx, s, strnlen(s, sizeof(s) - 1));
    }

    EVP_DigestFinal_ex(ctx, hash, &hash_size);
    EVP_MD_CTX_destroy(ctx);

    for (i = 0; i < hash_size; ++i)
    {
        printf("%02x", hash[i]);
    }

    printf("\n");

    EVP_MD_CTX_cleanup(ctx);
    return 0;
}
```

I am using the following 21-byte file as input:

```
$ xxd testfile
0000000: 8c18 8425 ea30 2236 d472 47a0 38b9 003e  ...%.0"6.rG.8..>
0000010: 85ca 547e b1
```

Unfortunately, my generated SHA does not match what `sha1sum` returns:

```
$ sha1sum testfile
05a5e29ba59164ceee6bffbaec283ae5a6ecd66f  testfile
$ myhashprog < testfile
d8e5c7f4360beb2cabf7275d15293a711e5dfeb3
```

What am I doing wrong?

I notice that there is a `0x00` in the file which will look like a string terminator but I am not sure how to handle it.  Maybe `fgets()` isn't the proper function to read from the file in this case...

Comment: Yes, don't use fgets, just read raw bytes (you already know how many by the file size).

Comment: What if it's from a pipe?

Comment: Then you have to keep reading until you get "end-of-stream". You can update the digest in chunks, no need to read it all into memory at once. Either way, read raw bytes. Don't give special treatment to zero-bytes.

Comment: Using `read()` worked great.  Since there's no *official* answer I am inclined to delete the question.  Anyone mind?

Comment: @Stephen - I suggest leaving the question open. I performed a quick search for duplicates and I could not find one. Also, someone may comment on the use of `EVP_MD_CTX_destroy` and `EVP_MD_CTX_cleanup`. I think one is superflous, but I don't have the source code handy to check. It Thilo dies not answer, then maybe you can provide an official answer. It may help future visitors.

Answer (score 3):

I resolved this by using `read()` instead of `fgets()`:

```
while ((bytes = read(STDIN_FILENO, s, sizeof(s))) > 0)
{
    EVP_DigestUpdate(ctx, s, bytes);
}
```

The problem is that, although `fgets()` will read all the bytes, it does not return the number of bytes read so you can not reliably determine how much of the buffer is relevant unless you know the size of the input in advance.

Comment: The salient point here being that `fgets` wants to read a string and stops at a zero-byte. `read` will just read as many bytes as it can.

Comment: Thanks, I've updated my answer to make it more comprehensive.